# What is my CPU Temperature

Tags: cpu, temperature

to get my CPU temperatures i first typed `sudo sensors-detect` and confirmed everything with yes.

Then i typed `sudo service module-init-tools restart`

Now this is the output of `sudo sensors`, but which is my CPU temperature? (And what are the other temperatures?). There are no onboard or pcie graphic cards built-in.

Under full load:

```
it8720-isa-0228
Adapter: ISA adapter

fan1:        1461 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:        2250 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:        2295 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +28.0 C  (low  = +127.0 C, high = +127.0 C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +44.0 C  (low  = +127.0 C, high = +127.0 C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:        +60.0 C  (low  = +127.0 C, high = +127.0 C)  sensor = thermal diode
intrusion0:  ALARM

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +48.4 C  (high = +70.0 C)
                       (crit = +90.0 C, hyst = +87.0 C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:      124.33 W  (crit = 125.19 W)
```

Idle:

```
fan1:         722 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:        2280 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:        2319 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +27.0 C  (low  = +127.0 C, high = +127.0 C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +21.0 C  (low  = +127.0 C, high = +127.0 C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:        +19.0 C  (low  = +127.0 C, high = +127.0 C)  sensor = thermal diode
intrusion0:  ALARM

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +7.4 C  (high = +70.0 C)
                       (crit = +90.0 C, hyst = +87.0 C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       29.64 W  (crit = 125.19 W)
```

CPU: AMD FX 8350
Mainboard: GigaByte GA-970A-UD3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lm-sensors only reads raw data of the in-built sensors.

in fact there is no normalisation imposed to the manufacturers. (they can build how many sensors they want and where they want).

so in some case info is clear (like in previous example) in some others info is less pertinent. you can only make supposition. only the manufacturer could tell you.

Answer (score 26):

> k10temp-pci-00c3
>   Adapter: PCI adapter

This sensor is provided by the k10temp kernel module which handles the AMD CPU, see http://lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices. The related temperature is the CPU one.
IIRC it8720, is a common chip on the MB, not possible to say more without manufacturer specification.

Answer (score 1):

How many cores does your CPU have? The answer could be temp1, temp2, and temp3, each representing a separate core.
 
 Mine lists:
 acpitz-virtual-0
 Adapter: Virtual device
 temp1: +44.5°C (crit = +107.0°C)
 
 nouveau-pci-0100
 Adapter: PCI adapter
 temp1: +48.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +110.0°C)
 
 coretemp-isa-0000
 Adapter: ISA adapter
 Core 0: +45.0°C (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
 Core 1: +47.0°C (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

Comment: My CPU has 8 Cores. Temp1 seems to stay low, even if under full load, so i think this is somethign else.

Comment: In most results I've seen, including from other sites, the ISA adapter presents the CPU Temp info. However, it also tends to list each CPU temp by Core rather than temp1, temp2, etc.

Comment: Dumb side question, have you tried installing and running psensor to see if it gives you a more readable output?

Comment: Psensor is a graphical tool. I only use console.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner to get all your temperature zones is:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/...$/.0°C/'
INT3400 Thermal  20.0°C
pch_skylake      -47.0°C
SEN1             52.0°C
SEN2             48.0°C
SEN3             55.0°C
SEN4             58.0°C
B0D4             54.0°C
x86_pkg_temp     54.0°C
```

I have a four core CPU which are most likely appearing as `SEN1` through `SEN4` in Linux/Ubuntu.

Note there is a problem with `pch_skylake` temperature which I am researching.