# Conky does not show cpu temp

Tags: kernel, temperature, conky, sensors

I am trying to use conky to minitor my system but it is not showing CPU temperature, lm-sensors, hddtemp are installed, I answered yes to all questions running sensors-detect and at the end it shows:
"Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them."

I loaded the modules name:

/etc/init.d/kmod start
[info] Loading kernel module loop.
[info] Loading kernel module w83627ehf.
[info] Loading kernel module w83627ehf.

and running sensors shows:
sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +22.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +67.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       48.00 W  (crit = 115.11 W)

k10temp-pci-00cb
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +22.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00d3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +17.2°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +67.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00d4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       42.78 W  (crit = 115.11 W)

k10temp-pci-00db
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +17.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)

w83627dhg-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
in1:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
+3.3V:        +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in4:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
in5:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
in6:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
temp1:         -1.0°C  (high =  -1.0°C, hyst =  -1.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
temp2:         +0.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
temp3:         +0.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
cpu0_vid:    +0.000 V
intrusion0:  ALARM

then I look for the modules by module-assisstant as root and it could not find any of them. What should I do to have the CPU temp on conky? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254305/what-is-my-cpu-temperature) and note the answer by JeanFI.

Basically it amounts to needing to review the hardware specification which will tell you the output that relates to the CPU.

To add the display to conky once you are aware of the value (using k10temp-pci-00c3 in this example) you would insert:

```
$ exec sensors | grep 'k10temp-pci-00c3' | awk '{print $3}'}
```

The `grep` pipe is used to search the output of `sensors` and display only information that matches.

The `awk` pipe is used to select the correct field from the output of sensors/grep.  This means that you can substitute `$3` for another value if it is not displaying the correct part (i.e $1,$2,$all).